# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'React\ZMQ\Context' not found

Tags: php, composer

Не могу найти какую команду использовать для установки этих классов:

```js
use React\EventLoop\Factory;
use React\Socket\Server as Reactor;
use React\ZMQ\Context;
```

вот мой composer.json

```js
{
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.2",
        "monolog/monolog": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "ColorCore\\":"core/classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: без `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'` ничего работать не будет. Как и без `composer install`

Comment: ну я уж не настолько туп, чтобы не подключить загрузчик. И зачем писать composer install если я это установил через консоль

Comment: Что вы вкладываете в слова "установил через консоль"? у вас в каталоге с проектом есть каталог `vendor` (или в глобальном каталоге composer'a) ?

Comment: omposer require в корне. Ну решил отложить этот способ так что я вопрос удалю

Comment: Ну ещё банальна проблема может быть в том, что нужного класса действительно нет в библиотеках, которые вы установили.

Comment: Вот, может поможешь) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1092174/336396